# Save SQL Server 'Server Name' values when running SQL Server as user with different domain

Tags: sql-server, ssms

So I need to periodically run SSMS as a user other than the windows user I am logged into my machine as. This user has a different domain than the user I am logged into my computer as, therefore what I do is run a small batch file to with /netonly /user: domain\user against my isntance of ssms.exe. Then I put in my password and SSMS starts up.

The problem with this is that I need to run SSMS with both users in order to connect to various environments. Whenever I switch back and forth, I lose all of the saved servers in the Server name drop down list:
[Connect to Server modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOXr9.png)

Is there a way for me to maintain a list of servers specific to each user?

Comment: "Is there a way for me to maintain a list of servers specific to each user?" - Are you able to run of the instances within Windows Sandbox?

Comment: Have you tried setting-up linked servers on your target SQL Server?  Each linked server configuration can use a unique set of credentials, or use pass-through authentication.  Or perhaps try setting-up local ODBC connections using different credentials.